# Расшифровка дроби

Tags: числительные

Корректно
 ли при расшифровке чисел в документообороте использовать разговорную 
форму *тридцать шесть и шесть кг* или необходимо писать 
полностью: *тридцать шесть целых и шесть десятых кг*?

---

София, спасибо, но меня больше интересует вопрос, допустимо ли использовать разговорную форму при записи дроби, или в спорных случаях филологическая экспертиза укажет, что "тридцать шесть и шесть" это "36+6", т. е. 42 кг? Про то, что лучше использовать полную форму мне известно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, форма "тридцать шесть и шесть кг" не годится даже для устной речи, запись "тридцать шесть и шесть десятых кг" с точки зрения смысла оспорить вряд ли возможно, но лучше использовать стандарт "тридцать шесть целых шесть десятых кг".

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь можно посмотреть: Формы написания чисел в тексте документов  http://www.delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5297

Пример 4

Кредитор обязуется открыть заемщику возобновляемую кредитную линию с лимитом в сумме 100 000 000 (Сто миллионов) рублей 00 копеек для расчетов с поставщиками и подрядчиками по оплате сырья, упаковки и услуг на срок по 10 марта 2008 года под 11,5 (Одиннадцать целых пять десятых) процентов годовых.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, ответ уже содержится в вашем вопросе: "в *документообороте* использовать *разговорную* форму". В документах используется официально-деловой стиль, следовательно, разговорным формам там не место.